# Create a path diagram to summarise a bootstrapLavaan CFA model in R

Tags: r, bootstrapping, r-lavaan

I have been using bootstrapLavaan for the first time, to perform confirmatory factor analysis. It runs fine and I have been able to summarise the CFA output. However, I have not been able to create a path diagram. Here is how I create the model:

```
install(lavaan)

# Fit initial CFA model using lavaan
initial_cfa_model <- lavaan::cfa(initial_cfa_model_syntax, data = cfa_data_rmv, missing = "fiml")

# Create summary
initial_cfa <- summary(initial_cfa_model, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)

# Custom function to extract measures from bootstrapLavaan
custom_extract <- function(lavaan_obj) {
  
  # Extract fit measures
  fit_measures <- lavaan::fitMeasures(lavaan_obj, fit.measures = c("chisq", "cfi", "tli", "rmsea", "srmr", "aic", "bic"))
   
  # Extract coefficients
  coefs <- lavaan::coef(lavaan_obj)
  
  # Combine fit measures and coefficients
  combined_results <- c(fit_measures, coefs)
  
  # Return combined results
  return(combined_results)
}

# Bootstrap the initial CFA model
boot_cfa_model <- lavaan::bootstrapLavaan(initial_cfa_model, 
                                          R = boot_iterations, 
                                          iseed = seed, 
                                          FUN = custom_extract
                                          )
```

And here is how I successfully plot the initial CFA model:

```
install(semPaths)

# Plot the initial CFA model
initial_cfa_plot <- semPaths(initial_cfa_model, 
                             whatLabels = "est", 
                             edge.label.cex = 0.7, 
                             layout = "tree", 
                             intercepts = FALSE, 
                             residuals = FALSE, 
                             style = "lisrel", 
                             curveAdjacent = TRUE, 
                             rotation = 2)

initial_cfa_plot
```

But this won't work with the code below (primarily because bootstrapLavaan saves its output as a vector):

```
# Plot the boot CFA model
boot_cfa_plot <- semPaths(boot_cfa_model, 
                             whatLabels = "est", 
                             edge.label.cex = 0.7, 
                             layout = "tree", 
                             intercepts = FALSE, 
                             residuals = FALSE, 
                             style = "lisrel", 
                             curveAdjacent = TRUE, 
                             rotation = 2)

boot_cfa_plot
```

So, I'm not sure how to make this work and I've been at this for many hours now. I have to assume that there is a solution as such a plot is an expected output from a CFA.

Any help received with gratitude. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many more hours on this, I found a solution to update the initial plot with the parameters from the bootstrapped model. To do this, the clue was to look closeley at the structure of the initial CFA plot `str(initial_cfa_plot`, which then showed the label parameters that could be changed. Here is my code:

````
```{r}

    install(qgraph)

    # Create a new plot object for the updated plot with bootstrapped means
    boot_cfa_plot <- initial_cfa_plot
    #qgraph::qgraph(boot_cfa_plot)

    # Filter boot_param_means to only include relationships (factor loadings)
    boot_factor_loadings <- boot_param_means[grep("=~", names(boot_param_means))]

    # Update the edge labels using these filtered factor loadings
    for (i in 1:length(boot_factor_loadings)) {
      boot_cfa_plot$Arguments$edge.labels[i] <- round(boot_factor_loadings[i], 2)
    }

    # Extracting edge labels from initial_cfa_plot
    initial_labels <- initial_cfa_plot$Arguments$edge.labels

    # Extracting edge labels from boot_cfa_plot
    boot_labels <- boot_cfa_plot$Arguments$edge.labels

    # Printing out the values for comparison
    print("Initial CFA Plot Edge Labels:")
    print(initial_labels)

    print("Bootstrapped CFA Plot Edge Labels:")
    print(boot_labels)

    # Display the updated plot
    qgraph::qgraph(boot_cfa_plot)
````

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrapLavaan` is not supported by semPlot... You could propose a change to the `lavaan` reader function if you want it supported:

https://github.com/SachaEpskamp/semPlot/blob/master/R/lavaan.R

Comment: Thanks Sacha Epskamp, I've done so!